# How do I point to a different gitHub repository?

Tags: android, github, intellij-idea

I have a project that I have created in IntelliJ. Initially, I had shared the repository on gitHub. After inviting another developer to the project, I deiced that I was going to delete repository on gitHub and recreate it under a new name. The problem I have is that after deleting the project via gitHub's web interface, my IntelliJ project still points to the old repository. My question is, "How can I point IntelliJ to the new project?"

To recap:
I created a project with IntelliJ.
I shared said project to gitHub via IntelliJ's interface.
I deleted the repository via gitHub's interface.
I recreated a repository via gitHub's interface (making sure the gitignore is making use of the Android settings).
I'm unable to point my project within IntelliJ to the new repository.

Question: How do I point the project to make use of the new repository via IntelliJ 13.1.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the remote url through the command line:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/yourNewRepo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, VonC. Doing this way will also reflect in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Noiroi yes, since IntelliJ will get that remote information from the local `.gitconfig` within your repo. And a `git remote set-url` would have changed that very same .gitconfig` file.